# Extrainfo column in Sybase audit table

Tags: sap-ase, audit, audit-logging, sybase-ase15

i'm using Sybase ASE 15.0 and when reading the *extrainfo* column from *sysaudits_01* there are missing values. The manual says that in case of an update, the *previous value* and the *current value* will appear in the column. Tested different scenarios of updates, inserts, deletes but other than the words UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE nothing else appears.

Is there anything that should be turned on or something to do to be able to see the values?

Any help is appreciated.

L.E. Using sp_audit 'cmdtext', 'sa', 'all', 'on' --user level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sp_audit 'cmdtext', 'sa', 'all', 'on' --user level